# copy a member from one pds to another? using the jcl statement

Tags: copy, mainframe, zos

How can i use the IEBGENER utilty to copy a member from one pds to another.

something similar to this:

```
//myjob job1
// exec pg=eibgener
```

??

don't know the the rest.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the output PDS has already been created and contains
sufficient space, you
could try something like:

```
//jobname  your-jobcard-info                               
//stepname EXEC PGM=IEBGENER                    
//SYSUT1   DD DSN=input-pds(member),DISP=OLD 
//SYSUT2   DD DSN=output-pds(member),DISP=OLD
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                          
//SYSIN    DD DUMMY                               
//*
```

I think IDCAMS REPRO is more commonly used for this sort of thing these days.

Answer (score 0):

Most folks use [IEBCOPY](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=utilities-iebcopy-library-copy-program) for copying members from one PDS(E) to another.  Sample JCL is available by following the link.